# What's wrong with OpenLayers code?

Tags: openlayers-2

I've just tried some simple code from example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var map = OpenLayers.Map('map-content', {});
   var wms_serever_map = OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('Base l', 'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0', {layer:basic},
       {});
   map.addLayer(wms_serever_map);
   if(!map.getCenter()){
      map.zoomToMaxExtent();
   }
});
```

but chrome and firefox don't show me the map and throws error: `uncaught type error: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined Openlayers.js:127` Its rather interesting, because some time ago this code worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You trying to use OpenLayers before the document is loaded. $(document).ready(function() {}) is too early. Use`<body onload='init()'>.`

UPD.: I've found some errors in your script:

1) You should use 'new' keyword while creating new object (var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map-content', {}), var wms_serever_map = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS());

2) Modify {layer:basic} to {layers:'basic'}

Comment: problem is not here. I've just used jquery instead of usual javascript. But if I write what you said, the error will remain